Update Swagger when dynamically adding FastAPI endpoints
I would like to update the Swagger when adding a new endpoint dynamically.
To dynamically add endpoints, I am using the accepted answer to Reload routes in FastAPI during runtime.
This looks like the following:
import fastapi
import uvicorn
from uvicorn.config import LOGGING_CONFIG

app = fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.get("/add")
async def add(name: str):
    async def dynamic_controller():
        return f"dynamic: {name}"
    app.add_api_route(f"/dyn/{name}", dynamic_controller, methods=["GET"])
    return "ok"


def route_matches(route, name):
    return route.path_format == f"/dyn/{name}"


@app.get("/remove")
async def remove(name: str):
    for i, r in enumerate(app.router.routes):
        if route_matches(r, name):
            del app.router.routes[i]
            return "ok"
    return "not found"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("dynamic_router:app", host="0.0.0.0", workers=1, log_config=LOGGING_CONFIG, port=5000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

While this creates new functional endpoints, the Swagger UI does not update to reflect these changes.
Is there a way to update the Swagger? If not, can we force the reload?
Is there an entirely other way to go about it?
EDIT 1
As pointed out by @jonrsharpe's comment. This was already partially solved in the referenced answer. The lines app.openapi_schema = None and app.setup() allow for the Swagger to be updated when refreshing the page.
Is there a way to force the refresh?
EDIT 2
If someone tries to use this endpoint generation while using the router  mechanism, this is what I've done, still without being able to force the refresh.
generative_router.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI


def generative_router_generator(app: FastAPI) -> APIRouter:
    generative_router: APIRouter = APIRouter()

    def update_swagger():
        app.openapi_schema = None
        app.setup()

    @generative_router.get("/add", tags=["GEN"])
    async def add(name: str):
        async def dynamic_controller():
            return f"dynamic {name}"
        app.add_api_route(f"/dyn/{name}", dynamic_controller, methods=["GET"], tags=["DYN"])
        update_swagger()
        return "ok"

    def route_matches(route, name):
        return route.path_format == f"/dyn/{name}"

    @generative_router.get("/remove", tags=["GEN"])
    async def remove(name: str):
        for i, r in enumerate(app.router.routes):
            if route_matches(r, name):
                del app.router.routes[i]
                update_swagger()
                return "ok"
        return "not found"

    return generative_router

app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from fastapi_offline import FastAPIOffline

from generative_router import generative_router_generator


def generate_fastapi_app() -> FastAPI:
    fastapi_app: FastAPI = FastAPIOffline()

    generative_router: APIRouter = generative_router_generator(app=fastapi_app)
    fastapi_app.include_router(generative_router, prefix="/generative")

    return fastapi_app


app: FastAPI = generate_fastapi_app()

main.py
import uvicorn
from uvicorn.config import LOGGING_CONFIG


def main():
    uvicorn.run("app:app", host="0.0.0.0", workers=1, log_config=LOGGING_CONFIG, port=5000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here we use a generator for the generative_router router. This is done only to pass the main FastAPI object to use in the add and remove endpoints, necessary to ubdate the Swagger.

That answer does say you have to invalidate the OpenAPI cache and a comment tells you how: app.openapi_schema = None then app.setup().

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783994/reload-routes-in-fastapi-during-runtime#comment136442867_74035526
